# iText : PDFPTable - Not able to insert data in specific column

Tags: java, pdf, itext, apache-poi, pdf-generation

I have to create a table using iText PDF library. The table contains 3 columns and can have multiple rows. In any row, Any field can be empty or can have value.
I cannot find a way in iText to create cell in a specific column. So what's happening is if any entry comes null, My data for next column comes to first one.
Code snippet -

```
//Printing First column data
    if (!attributes.getJSONObject(i).isNull("First")) {
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(attributes.getJSONObject(i).getString("First"), h4));
        table.addCell(cell);
    }
//Printing Second column data
    if (!attributes.getJSONObject(i).isNull("Second ")) {
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(attributes.getJSONObject(i).getString("Second "), h4));
        table.addCell(cell);
    }
//Printing Third column data
    if (!attributes.getJSONObject(i).isNull("Third")) {
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(attributes.getJSONObject(i).getString("Third"), h4));
        table.addCell(cell);
    }
```

How can I handle this without explicitly checking for all the possible cases?

For generating excel table using Apache POI, I can very easily do this as I can insert data for a specific column in a row. Code snippet for excel that I have done -

```
 //Printing First column data
  if (!attributes.getJSONObject(i).isNull("First")) {
    row.createCell(1); //This will insert in first column
    row.getCell(1).setCellValue(attributes.getJSONObject(i).getString("First"));
  }
  //Printing Second column data
  if(!attributes.getJSONObject(i).isNull("Second")) {
    row.createCell(2); //This will insert in second column
    row.getCell(2).setCellValue(attributes.getJSONObject(i).getString("Second"));
  }
  //Printing Third column data
  if(!attributes.getJSONObject(i).isNull("Third")) {
    row.createCell(3); //This will insert in third column
    row.getCell(3).setCellValue(attributes.getJSONObject(i).getString("Third"));
  }
```

Is there any way in iText to achieve this? (To insert data in a specific column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IText fills the table cells with the cells as they come. Thus, you cannot skip empty cells. But why not simply add `Cell` instances with empty content in such a situation? E.g. in place of merely

```
if(!attributes.getJSONObject(i).isNull("Second")) {
    row.createCell(2); //This will insert in second column
    row.getCell(2).setCellValue(attributes.getJSONObject(i).getString("Second"));
}
```

you can do

```
row.createCell(2); //This will insert in second column
if(!attributes.getJSONObject(i).isNull("Second")) {
    row.getCell(2).setCellValue(attributes.getJSONObject(i).getString("Second"));
}
```

or probably

```
row.createCell(2); //This will insert in second column
if(!attributes.getJSONObject(i).isNull("Second")) {
    row.getCell(2).setCellValue(attributes.getJSONObject(i).getString("Second"));
} else {
    row.getCell(2).setCellValue("");
}
```